# Tomcat - RemoteIpValve - x-forwarded-for header is null

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elb

I have an application (JVM 1.8.0_31-b13, Spring MVC 4.2.4, Security 4.0.3) deployed on Tomcat 7 (7.0.68) and I'm using an AWS ELB to handle requests from client.
In my application, I try to get the client ip address using the X-forwarded-for header. If I don't find it, then I use the method getRemoteAddr of the HttpServletRequest class.
And I have noticed several things when I log informations in the application:

First:
The header x-forwarded-for is always null

Second:
The remote address is sometimes the same as the elb ip and sometimes it's the same as client ip address.
I have noticed that:

- when the remote address is the same as the client ip address then the request is considered as secured and the scheme is https (method isSecure and getScheme)
- when the remote address is the same as the elb address ip then the request is not considered as secured and the scheme is http (method isSecure and getScheme)

Here's the valve configuration in server.xml:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" internalProxies="172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" />
```

Here's an example of elb address ip: 172.31.xxx.xxx

I don't understand:

- Why the x-forwarded-for header is always null.
- And why some requests are considered as secured and some are not.

Comment: How are the listeners on your ELB configured exactly? Are you doing SSL termination at the ELB or in Tomcat?

Comment: @MarkB : listeners are configured this way ELB Protocol: HTTP / ELB Port : 80 / Instance Protocol : HTTP / Instance Port 8080 and ELB Protocol: HTTPS / ELB Port : 443 / Instance Protocol : HTTP / Instance Port 8080

Comment: The termination is done at the ELB

Comment: Are you sure the requests with the null x-forwarded-for header aren't simply the ELB health check requests? Also, you are accepting both HTTP and HTTPS requests from the ELB, and you should only expect the HTTPS requests to result in `isSecure == true`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's not ELB health check. About HTTP and HTTPS, for my tests, I only make requests using HTTPS.

Comment: Did you configure the ELB health checks to use HTTPS?

Comment: I was looking at the documentation for `RemoteIpValve` and it states: "x-forwarded-by header is null because only internal proxies as been traversed by the request. x-forwarded-by is null because all the proxies are trusted or internal." You might want to look into how the internal proxies setting causes values to be nulled out. It looks like x-forwarded-for will be nulled out and the IP address will be in `request.remoteAddr`

Answer (score 0):

you can use request.getRemoteAddr() in spring-boot 3.0+

when you pass x-forwarded-for header, its transferred into remoteAddress field of HttpServletRequest.